# How to fix this CASE statement in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my first attempt at CASE statement:

```
select store_name, sum(sales_amt) as salesamt,
    case
        when sum(sales_amt) between 0 and 1000 then 'C'
        when sum(sales_amt) between 1001 and 2000 then 'B'
        when sum(sales_amt) >= 2001 then 'A'
    end as grading
from transaction_table
where Brand = 'Nike'
group by store_name
```

The result showed correctly grading...

```
store_name     salesamt   grading
Nike AAA       1000          C
Nike BBB       2500          A
Nike CCC       1700          B
```

but when I changed from store_name to transaction_sales_date (which its data type is Date), my results went all wrong.

```
select month(transaction_sales_date) as monthly, sum(sales_amt) as salesamt,
    case
        when sum(sales_amt) between 0 and 10000 then 'C'
        when sum(sales_amt) between 10001 and 20000 then 'B'
        when sum(sales_amt) >= 20001 then 'A'
    end as grading
from transaction_table
where Brand = 'Nike'
group by month(transaction_sales_date)
order by monthly
```

the result showed like this...

```
monthly    salesamt    grading
1          12000        A
2          9000         A
3          23000        A
```

How can I fix this so it can show the correct grading?

Comment: have fixed the question

Comment: Total nitpick, but it's a CASE expression, not a CASE statement. :)

Comment: Please read the first couple of paragraphs in the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Are you sure the numbers in the BETWEEN are correct? Are they 10000, 20000 etc, or are they 1000, 2000 etc.? (because then `A` would be a correct result)

Comment: I think I made a mistake. I have already fixed the problem myself and the problem was that the number ranges I entered was wrong to begin with. Thanks for the suggestions guys.

Answer (score 0):

*The edited question invalidates my answer. The original question missed all the `SUM(...)`.*

All fields in the select list must either be listed in the GROUP BY or have an aggregate function applied to them.

E.g.:

```
select store_name, SUM(sales_amt) AS salesamt,
    case
        when SUM(sales_amt) between 0 and 1000 then 'C'
        when SUM(sales_amt) between 1001 and 2000 then 'B'
        when SUM(sales_amt) >= 2001 then 'A'
    end as grading
from transaction_table
where Brand = 'Nike'
group by store_name
```

Here `store_name` is listed as GROUP BY field --> okay. `sales_amt` has the aggregate function `SUM()` applied to it --> okay.

Same story for the other query:

```
select month(transaction_sales_date) as monthly, SUM(sales_amt) as salesamt,
    case
        when SUM(sales_amt) between 0 and 10000 then 'C'
        when SUM(sales_amt) between 10001 and 20000 then 'B'
        when SUM(sales_amt) >= 20001 then 'A'
    end as grading
from transaction_table
where Brand = 'Nike'
group by month(transaction_sales_date)
order by monthly
```

You cannot refer to column aliases, except in the ORDER BY clause. Therefore `SUM(sales_amt)` must be repeated in the CASE expression, but `monthly` can be used in the ORDER BY.

Of course, you can also use other aggregate functions like MAX, MIN, AVG or COUNT (to list only the most commonly used).